# Shortest path that has to include certain waypoints

Tags: neo4j, cypher, shortest-path

I’m trying to find the shortest path that connects an arbitrary collection of nodes. Both start and end can be any of the nodes in the collection, as long as they are not the same.
Standard cypher functions shortestPath() or allShortestPaths() fail because they find the shortest path from start to end and do not include waypoints.
The following cypher works, but is there a faster way?

```
//some collection of nodeids, as waypoints the path has to include
match (n) where id(n) IN [24259,11,24647,28333,196] 
with collect(n) as wps

// create possible start en endpoints
unwind wps as wpstart
unwind wps as wpend
with wps,wpstart,wpend where id(wpstart)<id(wpend)

// find paths that include all nodes in wps
match p=((wpstart)-[*..6]-(wpend))
where ALL(n IN wps WHERE n IN nodes(p))

// return  paths, ordered by length
return id(wpstart),id(wpend),length(p) as lp,EXTRACT(n IN nodes(p) | id(n)) order by lp asc
```

Update 23-10-2015:
With the latest Neo4j version 2.3.0, it is possible to combine shortestPath() with a WHERE clasue that is pulled in somewhere during the evaluation process. You then get a construct like this, in which {wps} is a collection of nodeIds.

```
// unwind the collection to create combinations of all start-end points
UNWIND {wps} AS wpstartid
UNWIND {wps} AS wpendid
WITH wpstartid,wpendid WHERE wpstartid<wpendid

// for each start-end combi,calculate shortestPath() with a WHERE clasue
MATCH (wpstart) WHERE id(wpstart)=wpstartid
MATCH (wpend) WHERE id(wpend)=wpendid
MATCH p=shortestPath((wpstart)-[*..5]-(wpend))
WHERE ALL(id IN {wps}  WHERE id IN EXTRACT(n IN nodes(p) | id(n))   )

//return the shortest of the shortestPath()s
WITH p, size(nodes(p)) as length order by length limit 1
RETURN EXTRACT(n IN nodes(p) | id(n))
```

This approach does not always work, since there is an internal optimization that determines at which stage the WHERE clause is applied. So beware, and be prepared to fall back to the more bruteforce approach in the beginning of the item.

Comment: Do you have any hints you could apply here on which order the waypoints might occur in?  Or could they occur in any order?

Comment: I think the "shortestPath" concept applies only from some identified A to B.  The way you formulate your question, you're talking about any/all nodes, as long as the path goes through the waypoint nodes.  The trouble with this question formulation is, what if going through the waypoint nodes isn't the shortest path from A to B?   Or do you want only A/B pairs whose legit shortestPath also has the property that it contains the waypoint nodes?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits your understanding of my question is correct. In fact , it's what in the Noe4j context is called a predicate. I need to have the shortestPath that goes through all waypoints, the order does not matter.

From Neo4j 2.3.0 onwards, the shortestPath() function has a mechanism to include the predicate , and it is taken into account, but it's not completely accurate yet. So when you have (a)-[]->(b) as directly related nodes and you have (a),(b),(c),(d),(e) as waypoints, it sometimes returns 0 results, where a shorter waypoint list, like (a),(b),(c),(d) may return (c),(d),(e),(b),(a)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be a really unsatisfying answer, but here goes:

The question you're asking I strongly suspect is reducible to the problem of [Hamiltonian Paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path).   This is a classic graph algorithm problem that turns out to be NP-complete.  So practically speaking, what that means is that while it might be possible to implement this, the performance is likely going to be horrific.

If you really must implement this, I'd probably recommend not using cypher, and instead building something with the neo4j traversal framework.  You can find sample code and algorithms online that will do at least a portion of this.   But more broadly, if your data is larger than trivial in size, the unsatisfying part of this answer is that I probably wouldn't do it at all.

Better options might be to decompose your graph into smaller sub-problems which you can work independently, or coming up with another heuristic method that gets you close to what you want, but not via this method.

Comment: I knew it had something to do with Lewis Hamilton  :) 
Thanks for your pointer. You may very well be right about the performance issues we'll run into.